# Error when reinstalling CDN tax receipt extension

Tags: extension, error, cdn-tax-receipts

I was having some trouble with the CDN tax receipt extension, so I uninstalled the extension. When I tried to reinstall, I got this error message:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Field: `name` must be unique. An conflicting entity already exists - id: 99
Return to home page.

Luca

Comment: How did you uninstall the extension? Did you do it through the extension screen or through the file system? I'm thinking when you uninstalled it, it left some stuff in the database which is causing conflict when you're reinstalling.

Comment: Is there any associated errors in the Civicrm Error log? There is a handy log viewer extension here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer